# Swapping vectors between DLLs

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dll

I have a C++ DLL A and DLL B. Dll A will call a function and that instead start a thread in Dll B.

Dll A will fill a vector which a function from DLL B will swap. The vector has a pointer element of Class LogObj.

```
class LogData
{
public:
    FunctionID funcID;
    INT fType;
    INT padSize;
    INT mapToDB;
    ULONG eTime;
    ULONG sTime;
    ULONG pCount;
    INT curChild;
    LogData* parent;
    vector<LogData*>* childList;
    LogData()
    {
        childList = new vector<LogData*>;
        childList->clear();
        pCount=0;
        padSize=0;
        curChild=0;
    }
    ~LogData()
    {
        vector<LogData*>::iterator itr = childList->begin();
        for(;itr!=childList->end();itr++)
        {
            delete *itr;
        }
        childList->clear();
        delete childList;
    }
};
```

The pointer to the above class will be in the vector. The vector is itself in the heap.

```
void ClassInDLLA::GetClassObj(vector<LogData*>* toSwaps)
{
    if(GetTogglingSwitch())
    {
        toSwaps->swap(*swapBucket);
    }
    else
    {
    }
    return;
};
```

By calling the above function from DLL B the vector will be swapped. Before swapping the "toSwaps" (argument) will be empty.

Now, the LogObj pointer(created in DLL A) and its values can be read from DLL B. In some point , i am facing crash with access violation exception. Why does that happen.? What i am doing is correct or wrong approach?

The crash occurs in this line of code

```
bool si = logObj->childList->empty();
```

When i am trying to access the vector inside the LogObj the crash occurs. But this crash is occurring somewhere in between the processing. I am deleting the childList and logObj only after all the processing in DLL B.

Comment: Have all the DLLs (and the main .EXE) been compiled with: (a) exactly the same version of compiler, (b) with exactly the same compilation options and (c) all use the shared runtime support ?  MS requires all of the above when sharing standard library collections between DLLs. GCC has weaker requirements but needs a very modern version.

Comment: @RichardCritten Both Dll projects are in same solution. I am not sure shared runtime support.. Where to check that?